# Rooting or downgrading ? which is first?

Tags: rooting, downgrade

I just bought a Samsung A3 SM-A300FU (The 2015 version) running on Android 5.0.2
To be able to run [SnoopSnitch](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/snoopsnitch/wiki/FAQ#Does-SnoopSnitch-run-on-Android-5-Lollipop), I'm supposed to

- Downgrade to Android 4.4.4
- Root the phone.

My question is : Which I'm supposed to do first ? Rooting or downgrading ? *And why* :)

Thanks

Comment: Both are independent, provided you are rolling back to stock. More important is to see if your device has 4.4.4 stock firmware. This [guide may help](http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://www.guidingtech.com/39929/lollipop-to-kitkat-samsung/&ei=1BJc0qaH&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=154&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1459779405&sig=APY536x-fwzxx_JlBIWVeHyeCDZ-AqNrTQ). If your device doesn't have stock 4.4.4 you will need to search for a custom ROM. To do that you have to root first

Comment: I'm new to this "Rooting-Downgrading" stuff, but while reading [this article on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-assist/samsung-galaxy-a3-help-downgrade-5-0-2-t3185435), it appeared to me that they are not that separated.

Comment: That is a separate case. OP there rooted his 4.4.4 version and then tried to upgrade. To put it simply, stock downgrade doesn't require root **but** a) stock firmware lower version for your device needs to be available b) availability does not mean, it will work smoothly, google gives you failed cases for your specific device. This is the scenario if you don't want to stock . If you are willing to switch to custom ROM you have to root first (warranty voided) to be able to flash custom ROM.

Comment: Research well and fully understand the risks- IMO, it is better to look for an alternative app that works without downgrade. Downgrade with samsung phones is prone to be messy